# ConnectionNotEstablished error in custom TestTask

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, activerecord, rake

I'm trying to write a custom Rake task to perform some tests for a class placed in the lib directory. This works for basic tests not requiring any models, but I need to actually test using some models. It's my first foray into more advanced rake usage and after going through some other hurdles I've got stuck on getting a ConnectionNotEstablished error.

Here's the rake task:

```
Rake::TestTask.new(:test => 'db:test:prepare') do |test|
  test.libs << 'test/sync'
  test.test_files = Dir['test/sync/*_test.rb']
  test.verbose = true
end
```

Here's the test that raise the ConnectionNotEstablished exception:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'app/models/city'
require 'foo'
require 'test/unit'

class SyncTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  @@sync = Foo::Sync.new('test')

  def test_cities
    assert City.all.size == 2 # the exception is raised at this point
    @@sync.cities
    assert City.all.size == 102
  end
end
```

Here's a unit test that is actually working:

```
require 'test_helper'

class CityTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "the truth" do
    assert City.all.size == 2
  end
end
```

I've tried using derive my test class from `ActiveSupport::TestCase` instead of `Test::Unit::TestCase` but it still raise a ConnectionNotEstablished error. I'm certainly doing something wrong, can anyone find what or tell of a better way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found out what the problem was, I've replaced the two first `require` call by:

```
require 'test_helper'
```

and added the test directory to the TestTask's libs attribute:

```
test.libs << 'test'
```